# How to use `Quantity` to convert Degrees of Latitude into Kilometers?

Tags: units, geography

I want to convert 0.018 **Degrees of Latitude** into kilometers using the `Quantity` function in Mathematica. Unfortunately I do not know what **Degrees of Latitude** are called in Mathematica? My desired code should look something like this:

```
x = Quantity[0.018, "DegreesLatitude"];
UnitConvert[x, "Kilometers"]
```

What are **Degrees of Latitude** called in Mathematica?

Comment: Historical fun fact:  the kilometer was originally defined such that the distance from the North Pole to the Equator was 10,000 km;  under that definition, one degree of latitude is 1000/9 = 111.1111... km.  Subsequent redefinitions (and the oblateness of the Earth) mean that that this isn't precisely accurate, but it's still true to within 1% or so.

Answer (score 6):

A solution using [`GeoDistance`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GeoDistance.html).

```
degreesLatitudeToKilometers[x_] := UnitConvert[GeoDistance[{0, 0}, {x, 0}] , "Kilometers"];

degreesLatitudeToKilometers[0.018]
```

[image]

Comment: I think you mean UnitConvert[GeoDistance[{0, 0}, {x, 0}], "Kilometers"].

Comment: Thanks, good spot

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1253499/simple-calculations-for-working-with-lat-lon-and-km-distance